# Regex - make this greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex pattern:

```
rxp = /\[!lang=([^}]+)\]/g
```

This looks at something like this:

```
[!lang=javascript]
var foo = 'bar';
```

And correctly returns `["javascript"]`:

```
var found = [], rxp = /\[!lang=([^}]+)\]/g, curMatch;
while( curMatch = rxp.exec( myCodeStringAbove) ) {
  found.push( curMatch[1] );
}

// found === ['javascript']
```

#### BUT

If I have brackets later:

```
[!lang=javascript]
var foo = 'bar';
var fubar = [];
```

It freaks out and returns:

```
["javascript] var foo = 'bar'; var fubar = ["]
```

#### WHAT I NEED

I need to modify my regex pattern so that even though there are brackets later, it is greedy and stops at the first bracket, as in the first example above.
How do I do this?

Comment: try to clarify your question, its not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an error in your character class. You forbbid a closing curly bracket instead of a square curly bracket:

```
rxp = /\[!lang=([^\]]+)]/g
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks! By the way, what's the best way to learn to speak regex? I've tried...

Comment: @dc2: You can take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/, reading the friedl book, and training.

Comment: @dc2 - Another way is to peruse SO `regex` tag for real world problem solving. There are some experts here.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to force greedy operator `+` to be lazy by adding `?` after it

```
/\[!lang=(.+?)\]/g
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aN7qJ5)